# Bottom Navigation View goes up with windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

I need windowSoftInputMode= adjustRezise for my layout so that my buttons go up with the keyboard. BUT I don't want my BottomNagivationView to be affected by this.
How can I solve such?

My BottomNavigationView comes from MainActivity.xml which is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"></FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

My manifest has android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" but I adjust it by code when I open the fragment with:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Here are some pictures so you could understand what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPhcM.jpg

So what I would like to know is how I could set the BottomNavigationView to do nothing on keyboard opening while I'd like my buttons to be affected by :
`getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem solved by just adding following line in manifest file.
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"

Comment: It didn't help , the idea is that I need to somehow make BottomNavigationView immune of any windowSoftInputMode modes or to have it set on Hidden but only for it

Answer (score 0):

add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` inside your activity tag into your manifest file.
then go to your activity and change the parent layout to RelativeLayout, then create your FrameLayout which holds your fragments inside your relative layout which is your parent layout. Then add your second layout which is LinearLayout that holds the bottomNavigationView and make its Height and width match_parent but below the FrameLayout.
Below is the example of the main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

//FrameLayout which holds all your fragments
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragments_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">



</FrameLayout>


//BottomNavigationView Container
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragments_container">

    //BottomMenus
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_4_dash"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        //Container of Menus
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            //BottomMenu One
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/home_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Home" />
            </LinearLayout>

             //BottomMenu Two
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/contact_icon" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Contact" />
            </LinearLayout>


            //BottomMenu Three
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/about_icon" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="About"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

             //BottomMenu Four
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="17dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/services_icon" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Services"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then go to your fragment which you want to scroll and design it like below one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Title Of Your Form"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/f_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/m_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/l_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:hint="Message"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Send Messagge"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

That is how i solved it,
if you have any doubt please let me know but if its helps or looks like a correct answer please mark it as a correct answer thanks.